# Is this subset a basis of the vector space $V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

> Decide if the following subset is a basis of this vector space $V$:
>
> $$\left\{v_{1},v_{2}\right\}= \left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\  2 
> \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\  1  \end{pmatrix}\right\}
> \text{ in V = }\mathbb{R}^{2}$$ for an arbitrary fixed $\alpha \in
> \mathbb{R}, \alpha \neq \frac{1}{2}$

I'm not sure how to do it but I think if $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ are linear independent then the subset will be a basis of the vector space $V$?

So I tried to do that:

$$x\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\  2 
\end{pmatrix}+y\begin{pmatrix} \alpha \\  1  \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\  0  \end{pmatrix}$$

$$I: x+y\alpha=0$$

$$II: 2x+y=0$$

$II: y=-2x$

Put that in $I:x-2x\alpha=0$

We need to divide by $x$ now and we must say $x \neq 0$ here else we cannot divide, so we see already this cannot be linear independent. But let's continue:

$1-2\alpha = 0$

$2\alpha = 1$

$\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$ task excluded this solution but anyway, conclusion stays this is not linear independent and thus the subset is not a basis of $V$.

I hope this is alright or is it done completely different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic is flawed, and you make several statements that have no real basis.

For example, you say

> we must say $x \neq 0$ here else we cannot divide

But this is not true. You don't **have** to say that. Nobody is forcing you, and in fact, saying $x\neq 0$ is only one part of the solution.

**remember**: what you want to prove is that $x=0,y=0$ is the **only** solution to the equation $x v_1 + y v_2 = 0$.

---

What you have to do is seperate the cases. Indeed, if $xv_1+yv_2=0$, then $x-2x\alpha = 0$.

This leaves you with two options.

1. $x=0$. In this case, you can go on to show that $y=0$ as well.
2. $x\neq 0$. In this case, you have already proven that $\alpha=\frac12$ which is impossible.

So, you can conclude that the two vectors **are** independent.

---

Alternatively, you can transform the equation $x-2x\alpha=0$ into $$x(1-2\alpha)=0$$

and then divide the equation by $(1-2\alpha)$ (*why can you do that?*) to get $x=0$.

Comment: Haha this is awesome because $\alpha \neq \frac{1}{2}$ so ($1-2\alpha) \neq 0$

Comment: @cnmesr Exactly. In fact, if $\alpha=\frac12$, then the two vectors *are* linearly dependent.

Answer (score 2):

> Put that in $I:x-2x\alpha=0$
>
> We need to divide by $x$ now and we must say $x \neq 0$ here else we cannot divide, so we see already this cannot be linear independent. But let's continue:

You don't have to divide; continue like this:

$$x-2x\alpha=0 \iff x(1-2\alpha)=0$$

So either $\alpha = \tfrac{1}{2}$, but this value is excluded, or $x=0$. So we have $x=0$ and from $y=-2x$, also $y=0$. But that means the vectors are in fact linearly independent!

Note that for a basis, you also need that the two vectors span $V$, but since the dimension is $2$, you may know that any 2 linearly independent vectors will indeed span the space.

Answer (score 2):

To your proof: From  $x-2x\alpha=0$ we get $x(1- 2 \alpha)=0$. Hence $ \alpha=1/2$ or $x=0$. Since $ \alpha \ne 1/2$, we get $x=0$. From $2x+y=0$ we finally derive $y=0$.

Thus :  $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linear independent .